# Google Script to set description field on doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a script based on [this code](https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/01/21/script-for-generating-google-documents-from-google-spreadsheet-data-source/) to create invoices for clients by extracting data from a Google spreadsheet and replacing the relevant fields in a template document and creating a new copy.

It's working, however, I really need to fill in the description field for the new document as well. Is there any way to do this programmatically via my Script?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, as soon as I've posted this question I've stumbled across the answer. Quite simple:

[setDescription(description)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setdescriptiondescription)

It seems it works for documents as well as forms. So for example:

```
    var source = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceId);
    var newFile = source.makeCopy('My New File');
    newFile.setDescription('My description here');
```